# Получаю ошибку при попытке создать или обновить рейтинг товара

Tags: django

в общем получаю ошибку

```
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: UNIQUE constraint failed: catalog_rating.user_id
```

вот код модели

```
class Rating(models.Model):
    """Рейтинг"""
    star = models.ForeignKey(RatingStar, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name="звезда")
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name="Товар", related_name="ratings")
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.star} - {self.product}"

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Рейтинг"
        verbose_name_plural = "Рейтинги"
```

обработчик views

```
class AddStarRating(View):
    """Добавление рейтинга продукта"""
    form_class = RatingForm
    template_name = 'add_rating'

    def post(self, request):
        form = self.form_class(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            print(request.user.id)
            Rating.objects.update_or_create(
                user_id = request.user.id,
                product_id=int(request.POST.get("product")),
                star_id= int(request.POST.get("star"))
            )
            
            return HttpResponse(status=201)
        else:
            return HttpResponse(status=400)
```

не понятно почему я получаю такую ошибку при попытке обновить рейтинг. При выводе id_user что я подставляю выдает такой же как и записан в бд, но рейтинг не обновляется.

Comment: Попробуйте заменить OneToOneField на ForeignKey. Так же советую [глянуть](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#update-or-create) как работает update_or_create.

Comment: @5c0rp помогло, спасибо!